# How do I take Clash of Clans off of my iPad? I don't want it anymore

Tags: ipad

I no longer want Clash of Clans on my iPad.  How can I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Tap and hold on the app icon. It should start wiggling and have a little "X" on one of the corners. Tap that and confirm with the message that you're deleting it.